# how to group by in pandas and tabulate value frequencies

Tags: pandas-groupby, frequency, tabulate

I have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1,1,6,6,6,2],'col2':[1,1,1,4,4,4,5,2]})
```

[image]

I want:

to group by each value in `col1` and then show the tabulated frequencies in the second column (ie, there are 3 1s and 1 4 in group 1 shown as 1:3, 4:1, ie value:frequency).

I would also like to have the list sorted in descending order based on count

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this the most efficient answer, but the solution I found was:

```
gpby = df.groupby('col1')
vals = []
for i, row in gpby:
    v = row.col1.values[0]
    c = row.shape[0]
    vc=row.col2.value_counts().reset_index().values.tolist()
    row_values = (v,c,vc)
    vals.append(row_values)
    
new_df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=['value','cnt','vc'])
new_df
```

[image]